# Exchange Size problems

Tags: exchange-2003

I have an email mailbox that is giving me the following error

A non-delivery report with a status code of 5.2.2 was generated for recipient rfc822;total@domain.co.uk (Message-ID <3AF4562FBE303E479EF20EC2F0FD03E7446D27@server01.domain.local>).
Causes: In Exchange 2000, the delivery status notification(DSN)is generated because the recipientÆs mailbox exceeded its storage limit.  In Windows 2000 or Windows .NET, the DSN is generated when the storage size of drop directory exceeds the SMTP virtual server disk quota.  The quota size is 11 times the maximum messages size or 22 MB if there is no max message size.  If the storage size of the drop directory is within one maximum message size of the quota or 2MB is no maximum message size is defined), the system  assumes that this message  cause the storage size to exceed  the quota, so this DNS is generated.
Solution: Check the mailbox storage or the queue storage quota limit.

But I have increased the quota size so it shouldn't be producing this error any more, any one got any other suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several parameters to set the quota.

1. There are the organization's Global settings / Message delivery properties setting the default values for maximum message size for sent and received messages for your information stores, **no matter which protocol is used**
2. there is the virtual SMTP server's properties setting the maximum message size **for SMTP reception only**
3. there is the SMTP connector's property to only allow message smaller than X KB **for SMTP outgoing mail only**

To effectively change anything for mail reception, you would need to check at least 1. and 2.